# Keyword search on all columns of multiple tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, search, keyword

We are maintaining the profile information’s (like profile first name, last name, address, city, state, age, religion, occupation, education, etc….) from `tbl_profie` table in SQL Server.

The users can search profiles using any keywords like

```
Example 1: MBBS, Delhi, India
Example 2: MBA, Delhi, cricket
Example 3 : London, Hindu
```

`Tbl_profile` table defending some parent table like `Tbl_city, Tbl_state, Tbl_country, Tbl_occupation, Tbl_education` tables, etc.

So how to fetch user search results from `Tbl_profile` and profiles related tables using user’s keyword with easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a perfect job for [Full Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)